# Where is the memory allocation of "__this_module" variable?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

From `<linux/module.h>`:

```
#ifdef MODULE
#define MODULE_GENERIC_TABLE(gtype,name)            \
extern const struct gtype##_id __mod_##gtype##_table        \
  __attribute__ ((unused, alias(__stringify(name))))

extern struct module __this_module;
#define THIS_MODULE (&__this_module)
#else  /* !MODULE */
#define MODULE_GENERIC_TABLE(gtype,name)
#define THIS_MODULE ((struct module *)0)
#endif
```

I can see "`extern struct module __this_module;`" is just a declaration of `__this_module`, but not definition of `__this_module`. So where is the memory allocation of `__this_module`? I can't find it in `kernel` code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [an obscure and dark spot in the LKML](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0011.0/0710.html)...

> Does this mean that the module structure (struct module) and it's various
>    ubstructures are filled in by insmod?
>
> Regards,
>   Naren
>
> On Sun, 5 Nov 2000, Tigran Aivazian wrote:
>
> > On Sun, 5 Nov 2000, Naren Devaiah wrote:
> >     >
> >     >
> >
> > > I've looked in the 2.4.0-pre10 source tree and found it defined as
> > >       extern struct module __this_module;
> > >       in module.h (among other files), but where is it actually defined?
> >
> > it isn't -- it's magic, of course :). The way it works is for insmod to
> >     arrange things in such a manner that &__this_module resolves to point to
> >     the beginning of module's address space, which happens to contain 'struct
> >     module' at the beginning.
> >
> > Regards,
> >     Tigran

[Follow-up](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0011.0/0712.html)...

> On Sun, 5 Nov 2000, Naren Devaiah wrote:
>
> > Does this mean that the module structure (struct module) and it's various
> >     substructures are filled in by insmod?
> >
> > Regards,
> >     Naren
>
> Yes, partially, i.e. have a look at sys_create_module() and
>   sys_init_module() system calls, they are in kernel/module.c
>
> sys_create_module() just allocates the space and links the module into the list but sys_init_module() is passed a 'struct module' from userspace
>   whose content is harshly validated (trust no one!) and then installed into
>   a real kernel 'struct module' and module's init_module() routine is
>   invoked.
>
> Regards,
>   Tigran